# ORA-28759: failure to open file despite permissions

Tags: oracle, plsql, wallet

I'm working with Oracle 18c.

I want to make plsql procedures that retrieve data (GET/POST) from api through httsp protocol.

So, it work using http, but not with https despite all my efforts.

Below, my code :

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
declare
    v_req       utl_http.req;
    v_res       utl_http.resp;
    v_buffer    varchar2(4000); 
begin
    utl_http.set_wallet('file:Z:\Documents\dev\plsql_http_request\wallets\ewallet.p12','iciC29000!');
    v_req := utl_http.begin_request('https://www.google.com/');
    v_res := utl_http.get_response(v_req);
    utl_http.read_text(v_res, v_buffer, NULL);
    utl_http.end_response(v_res);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_res.status_code);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_res.reason_phrase);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_buffer);
end;
```

I have, off course, generate a wallet using orapki. I make folder and file himself set to convenient permissions (but i have some doubts) :
[permissions of my wallet and folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8sbo.png)

Thanks a lot for your help :-) !

Comment: According to your screenshot, the path is `...\wallets\wallet.p12`, not `...\wallet\wallet.p12` ?

Comment: well seen ! but i check my code and il's just a mistake in my stackoverflow's post...

Comment: I'm not sure about this case, but in other cases the path does not contain filename `wallet.p12` which is implicit. But only a directory.

Comment: well seen ! it's managed to get rid off "ora-28759-failure-to-open-file-despite-permissions". i have now this error : ORA-29106: Cannot import PKCS #12 wallet.

Comment: I found this extremely helpful:  Edit the sqlnet.ora file. WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="$TNS_ADMIN")))
Make sure you set $TNS_ADMIN
https://www.talkapex.com/2021/01/connecting-to-oracle-cloud-database-ora-28759-failure-to-open-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just have to specify location of the directory, not of the file.

correction :

```
    utl_http.set_wallet('file:Z:\Documents\dev\plsql_http_request\wallets\','iciC29000');
```

instead of :

```
    utl_http.set_wallet('file:Z:\Documents\dev\plsql_http_request\wallets\ewallet.p12','iciC29000');
```

Comment: This is not an answer, you are adding information to your question with more steps you have taking trying to solve your problem, but the problem remains unsolved, so you should have edited your question adding the new details.

Comment: it's done, is it good ?